# show popup on tabbar button click react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm working on an old project where tabbar is created using the Scene from 'react-native-router-flux'.
There are five tabs, currently all are showing a particular class component, Bu my requirement hear is that I want to show a popup when click on the center tab and that popup should be shown on over that is open before that tabbar button click.

is this possible to achieve ?, currently I created a whold component with a small popup at the bottom, I tried making the background transparent to show the background view but it didn't work,

[image: Currently showing]

I have created the tabbar like this

```
import { Scene, Router, ActionConst, Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';




<Router>
<Scene key="root" hideNavBar>
    <Scene key="main" tabBarStyle={styles.tabBarStyle} hideNavBar >
      <Scene
        key="tabbar"
        tabs
        showLabel={false}
      >
        <Scene key='phonebookTab' title="Phonebook" icon={TabIcon} initial >
          <Scene
            key="phonebook"
            component={HomeScreen}
            title='Phonebook'
            activeTintColor={colors.darkishPurple}
            hideNavBar
          />
        </Scene>
        <Scene key='contactsTab' title="Contacts" icon={TabIcon} >
          <Scene
            key="ContactsScreen"
            component={ContactsScreen}
            title='Contacts'
            activeTintColor={colors.darkishPurple}
            hideNavBar
          />
        </Scene>
        <Scene key='myNetworkTab' title="My Network" icon={TabIcon} >
          <Scene
            key="myNetwork"
            component={Contact}
            title='My Network'
            activeTintColor={colors.darkishPurple}
            hideNavBar
          />
        </Scene>
        <Scene key='groupsTab' title="Groups" icon={TabIcon}>
          <Scene
            key="groups"
            component={Group}
            title='Groups'
            activeTintColor={colors.darkishPurple}
            hideNavBar
          />
        </Scene>

        <Scene key='settingsTab' title="Settings" icon={TabIcon}>
          <Scene
            key="settings"
            component={Settings}
            title="Settings"
            activeTintColor={colors.darkishPurple}
            hideNavBar
          />
        </Scene>
      </Scene>
    </Scene>
<Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

please follow this link and Create Custom tab bar and set button click to show popup:-

https://medium.com/@iakash1195/custom-tabbed-navigation-in-react-native-router-flux-47d1ad12ce2e

if any question then ask me.

Comment: I have created the customtabbar, how should I show popup on tabbar button click ?

Comment: use this npm for popup or tooltip https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-walkthrough-tooltip